# How to use sass interpolation inside Tailwind css @apply directive?

Tags: visual-studio-code, sass, tailwind-css, interpolation, postcss

I'm trying to use sass interpolation inside a tailwind apply directive (see example below).
According to VSCode the syntax below is incorrect (`at-rule or selector expectedscss(css-ruleorselectorexpected)`).
However postcss outputs the built css without any errors.

```scss
$colorTypes: "primary", "success", "warning", "danger";

@each $colorType in $colorTypes {
  .card-#{$colorType} {
    @apply bg-#{$colorType};
  }
}
```

Is this a VSCode error?
Is there any way to fix it?
Is there an other to way have variables inside an apply statement?

Screenshot:
[image: error screenshot]

`tailwind.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{html,js,jsx,ts,tsx}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
    colors: {
      primary: "#111111",
      success: "#222222",
      warning: "#333333",
      danger: "#444444",
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a VSCode error with the built-in Sass syntax interpreter not quite understanding `@apply`, since that at-rule is Tailwind specific. You can safely ignore the error or turn the error off in VSCode settings.

Comment: I would rather not fully disable `css-ruleorselectorexpected` since I would still like to get notified if there are some "valid" related syntax errors.

Comment: If I were to temporarily disable the error until I can find a more permanent solution, how would I go about doing that? there doesn't seem to be a `css.ruleorselectorexpected` option in `settings.json`

Comment: As per [the documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/css#_customizing-css-scss-and-less-settings), you'd need to disable all SCSS validation by setting `scss.validate` to `false`.

Comment: So I would probably have to install something like stylelint in that case, thanks for the help